# IBM APP ID with ADFS using windows integrated authentication WIA

Tags: ibm-appid

I Need help with **APP ID** service in **IBM Cloud**.

I have a configuration with a Loopback application residing in IBM Cloud which uses the **APP ID** service to perform **SSO** automated login.

**APP ID** service is configured with one identity provider:

SAML 2.0 Federation
**SAML Federation** is configured to work with **ADFS** which I have setup with an Azure virtual machine for test and our customers production **ADFS**.

The solution works and my **SSO** request is relayed:

```
> APP ID > ADFS
```

and authentication is performed and I can log in to the system.

**Problem:**

The problem is that **ADFS** is always using the **Form-based Authentication**, but I need to use the **Windows Integrated Authentication** i.e. the customer when logged in to the corporate network is never asked for credentials.

I have together with the ADFS administrator troubleshoot the windows side and can not see any irregularities.

**Questions:**

1. Does **APP ID** service support **Windows Integrated Authentication** and what can I do to enable it?
2. How to troubleshoot the workings of **APP ID** service, logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the AuthnContext using the management API -

https://<region-endpoint>.appid.cloud.ibm.com/swagger-ui/#/Management%20API%20-%20Identity%20Providers/mgmt.set_saml_idp

`urn:federation:authentication:windows` is currently not supported.
However, you can try updating the `authnContext` to either `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified` or just an empty object (`"authnContext": {}`)

In my experience, it works for me by updating with an empty object.

Ref
Managing App ID with the API : https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-manging-api